# Java Collection performance

Tags: java, java-8, performance-testing, primitive-types

I just tried a test example on codility. The task was: " ... given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.".

Plus:

- N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
- each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

my firts attempt was a typical Java 8 solution:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {

     Set<Integer> l = Arrays
            .stream(A)
            .boxed()
            .filter(i -> i > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return IntStream
            .iterate(1, a -> a + 1)
            .filter(i -> !l.contains(i))
            .findFirst()
            .getAsInt();
}
```

All correct, but the tests for intermediate size test arrays, ran into a timeout.

Second try (plain old java):

```
public int solution(int[] A) {

    boolean[] B = new boolean[1000001];

    for (int a : A) {
        if (a > 0) {
            B[a] = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        if (!B[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This version was incedibly much faster, especially for short arrays A.

Questions:

- Am I missing something with my first attempt?
- Are there tweaking options?
- Is the test on codility premature, and in reallity the difference is expected to disappear, almost entirely?
- Does anyone have a better Java 8 solution?

**Test results first version:**

▶ example1 
first example test ✔OK
1. 0.108 s OK

▶ example2 
second example test ✔OK
1. 0.104 s OK

▶ example3 
third example test ✔OK
1. 0.104 s OK

▶ extreme_single 
a single element ✔OK
1. 0.100 s OK
2. 0.104 s OK
3. 0.104 s OK
4. 0.100 s OK

▶ simple 
simple test ✔OK
1. 0.100 s OK
2. 0.104 s OK
3. 0.100 s OK

▶ extreme_min_max_value 
minimal and maximal values ✔OK
1. 0.100 s OK
2. 0.104 s OK

▶ positive_only 
shuffled sequence of 0...100 and then 102...200 ✔OK
1. 0.100 s OK
2. 0.104 s OK

▶ negative_only 
shuffled sequence -100 ... -1 ✔OK
1. 0.100 s OK

▶ medium 
chaotic sequences length=10005 (with minus) ✘TIMEOUT ERROR 
running time: 0.136 sec., time limit: 0.100 sec.
1. 0.136 s TIMEOUT ERROR,  running time: 0.136 sec., time limit: 0.100 sec.
2. 0.128 s TIMEOUT ERROR,  running time: 0.128 sec., time limit: 0.100 sec.
3. 0.144 s TIMEOUT ERROR,  running time: 0.144 sec., time limit: 0.128 sec.

▶ large_1 
chaotic + sequence 1, 2, ..., 40000 (without minus) ✔OK
1. 0.588 s OK

▶ large_2 
shuffled sequence 1, 2, ..., 100000 (without minus) ✔OK
1. 0.748 s OK
2. 0.660 s OK

▶ large_3 
chaotic + many -1, 1, 2, 3 (with minus) ✔OK
1. 0.444 s OK

**Test results second version:**

▶ example1 
first example test ✔OK
1. 0.004 s OK

▶ example2 
second example test ✔OK
1. 0.004 s OK

▶ example3 
third example test ✔OK
1. 0.004 s OK

▶ extreme_single 
a single element ✔OK
1. 0.004 s OK
2. 0.008 s OK
3. 0.004 s OK
4. 0.008 s OK

▶ simple 
simple test ✔OK
1. 0.004 s OK
2. 0.004 s OK
3. 0.008 s OK

▶ extreme_min_max_value 
minimal and maximal values ✔OK
1. 0.008 s OK
2. 0.004 s OK

▶ positive_only 
shuffled sequence of 0...100 and then 102...200 ✔OK
1. 0.008 s OK
2. 0.004 s OK

▶ negative_only 
shuffled sequence -100 ... -1 ✔OK
1. 0.008 s OK

▶ medium 
chaotic sequences length=10005 (with minus) ✔OK
1. 0.024 s OK
2. 0.024 s OK
3. 0.032 s OK

▶ large_1 
chaotic + sequence 1, 2, ..., 40000 (without minus) ✔OK
1. 0.220 s OK

▶ large_2 
shuffled sequence 1, 2, ..., 100000 (without minus) ✔OK
1. 0.244 s OK
2. 0.244 s OK

▶ large_3 
chaotic + many -1, 1, 2, 3 (with minus) ✔OK
1. 0.172 s OK

**Bottom line:**
Especially the tests with small sized arrays are two orders of magnitude faster with just plain java. For large arrays its 'only' a factor of 3.

**EDIT:**

Accoring to the comments I just tried to get deeper into the problem and tried:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {

boolean[] B = new boolean[1000001];

for (int a : A) {
    if (a>0){
        B[a] = true;
    }
}

 return IntStream
        .iterate(1, a -> a + 1)
        .filter(i -> !B[i])
        .findFirst()
        .getAsInt();

}
```

**Result:**

▶ example1 
first example test ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK

▶ example2 
second example test ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK

▶ example3 
third example test ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK
collapse allCorrectness tests

▶ extreme_single 
a single element ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK
2. 0.096 s OK
3. 0.096 s OK
4. 0.096 s OK

▶ simple 
simple test ✔OK
1. 0.100 s OK
2. 0.096 s OK
3. 0.100 s OK

▶ extreme_min_max_value 
minimal and maximal values ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK
2. 0.100 s OK

▶ positive_only 
shuffled sequence of 0...100 and then 102...200 ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK
2. 0.096 s OK

▶ negative_only 
shuffled sequence -100 ... -1 ✔OK
1. 0.096 s OK
collapse allPerformance tests

▶ medium 
chaotic sequences length=10005 (with minus) ✘TIMEOUT ERROR 
running time: 0.116 sec., time limit: 0.112 sec.
1. 0.116 s TIMEOUT ERROR,  running time: 0.116 sec., time limit: 0.112 sec.
2. 0.116 s TIMEOUT ERROR,  running time: 0.116 sec., time limit: 0.100 sec.
3. 0.124 s OK

▶ large_1 
chaotic + sequence 1, 2, ..., 40000 (without minus) ✔OK
1. 0.340 s OK

▶ large_2 
shuffled sequence 1, 2, ..., 100000 (without minus) ✔OK
1. 0.408 s OK
2. 0.372 s OK

▶ large_3 
chaotic + many -1, 1, 2, 3 (with minus) ✔OK
1. 0.272 s OK

**Conclusion:**

- For small sized test arrays it is almost equally slow like the first version, thus here the IntStream seems to be the bottle neck.
- For large test arrays the speed seems to be intemediate. Thus I'm not really sure what it should tell me.

**Edit 2:**

I actually just found an article describing the issue partly: https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html . Therein, the author claims the difference between streams and for loop running over arrays is due to the fact that streams are quite new. However the article is dated 4 years ago.

Comment: why are you assuming that streams should outperform plain old loops?

Comment: There's a lot of boxing/unboxing going on in your stream solution.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I didn't claim, I  expect the stream to faster. However, I expected a difference of maybe some percentage, thus not interesting for most real world applications. But two orders of magnitude, and even a factor of three is way more than I expected.

Comment: @LutzHorn I don't have acces to the backing java process. It is run by codility.

Comment: @Nexevis I don't compare streams with collections.

Comment: @PeMa Your title is literally "Java Collection Performance"

Comment: @Nexevis True, but I compare to arrays of primitives.

Comment: @Nexevis To be true, not even sure, what makes the difference here ... that's why I'm asking the experts.

Comment: It's hard to write an appropriate answer here. There's some speculation, and probably *several* possible reasons for the performance differences. One reason might also be that this "codility"-Page is likely to do some sort of "one-shot" execution: It does not do a warmup, and the JIT does not have a chance to kick in. If you executed the stream-based variant multiple times, it's likely to become faster (but how much...? That's hard to say, considering that unboxing etc. still have to happen...)

Comment: @Marco13  I was asking since I wanted to get a deeper understanding about what really makes a difference, when performance matters. After the two edits, it seems that the main difference here are the streams compared to for loops. So, I think an accepted answer maybe to explain what causes this difference, what is really behind streams, and how to improve. Or a reasoning that all this is just due to bad performance testing practice. I can't do performance tests reliably myself, since I don't know, how to "warm up" the JVM appropriately, e.g. how to make the JIT decide to compile the streams.

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything. Boxing integers and checking HashSets is slower than iterating a primitive array. The only change I would make to your second solution is to replace the `boolean[]` with a [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html), which is similar to a `boolean[]` but more space-efficient as it uses just one bit per element.

Comment: I made an edit to my question accordingly. It seems like, the search in the HashSet doesn't make the big difference far small test arrays.

Comment: And yes, I remember the BitSet (from long in the past). True, this should help. But it's not related to my point in the question.

Comment: @PeMa it’s not clear, what the point of your question is. You are creating two code snippets doing entirely different things, which has nothing to do with the Stream API (setting boolean entries of an array *is* an entirely different thing than populating a `HashSet<Integer>`, further, the loops stop at `1000000` whereas the stream is infinite, rather than an equivalent `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000000)`). You didn’t document your measuring method.

Comment: @MikeFHay Using a `BitSet` for this task is more than just “more space-efficient”, as searching for the smallest number via `.nextClearBit(1)` will test 64 bits at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between those two pieces of code. I suspected that the largest difference comes from using `Set<Integer>` vs `boolean[]`, so I wrote a little test:

```
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int n : numbs) {
            set.add(n);
        }
```

vs

```
        boolean[] arr = new boolean[numbs.length];
        for (int n : numbs) {
            arr[n] = true;
        }
```

The difference was 20x with 1000000 numbers in range [0, 1000000).

Comment: Well I actually suspected the same had the same. But as seen in the edit, for small test arrays this is not what makes the large real difference.

Comment: The problem with this solution at the end of the post is that it doesn't test to see whether the result, `.getAsInt() - 1` is in `A` (which it could be).

Comment: @scottb; My solution was wrong. I removed it.